# mysql search in the nth digit of a number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, math

I am thinking of saving the status of a user to an integer, so it could have 9 different status with 10 types in each status. (# # # # # # # # #)

For example, a registered user who has not paid and term. Status = 000011200.

Can I use MySQL to search for users with the status, eg, # # # # # # 2 # #?

Comment: You could take a look at bit-wise storage.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a near impossible-to-maintain idea. Yes, it's compact, but it's incomprehensible to a human, which makes it hard to work with. It's also nowhere near self-documenting; if you forget or mix up which number represents what you'll get into a whole load of problems and logic bugs.

You should be storing each separate kind of status in a separate column, and preferably use something as self-documenting as ENUMs as values:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    payment_status      ENUM('paid', 'pending', 'rejected'),
    registration_status ENUM('active', 'pending', 'deleted'),
    ...
)
```

Clean, simple, comprehensible, usable, maintainable, extendable; and probably a number of other *able more. I don't see any real advantage in using something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
)
```

to use SUBSTR

```
SELECT * FROM `test` 
WHERE SUBSTR( 
STATUS , 7, 1 ) = '2'
```

to use REGXP

```
SELECT * 
FROM `test` 
WHERE 
STATUS REGEXP '[0-9]{6}2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last two digits with `/100` and take only the last one with the `modulo 10` operator

```
select (status / 100) % 10
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast integer to char, then use LIKE operator with underscore as single wildcard character.

```
CAST(status as CHAR(9)) LIKE '______2__'
```

but I am sure you can find better database design to achieve this goal.

In design you intended to use, can't use index par example.

If you want to store two different type of information, store it in two different column. You will have a more easier database to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$n = 123456;
$digit = 5-1 //display 5th digit
echo substr($n,$digit,1);
```

In MySQL:

`select * from table where status like '____2%'`

this will select all record with 2 at 5th position....

But I would rather use int as record type and powers of 2... it is much quicker and simpler...

Lets say you got 4 attributes... so 4 powers of 2 are 1,2,4,8 ... if you want to mark second attribute as active you simply set value to 2 ... but when you want to set 2nd and 4th values to active, just set value to `2 | 4` (`insert into table (status) values (2 | 4)`) ... now you can read all record that have 2nd and 4th places marked by `select * from table where (status & 2) and (status & 4)`

Answer (score 0):

While this is just helping propagate a bad design, if you want to check for any particular digit, then [treat the number as a string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr):

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE SUBSTR(status, 7, 1) = '2'
```